# graph.adjacency returns adjecent vertices error

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to create a graph from an adjacency matrix :

```
        mari
femme      InghiP IngtiP TerangP TeronP TimungP UnknownP
  InghiP      219     75     159    108     173        3
  IngtiP       91     39      69     50      76        0
  TerangP     139     55     100     81     122        0
  TeronP      126     40      82     68      82        0
  TimungP     167     74     121    116     128        2
  UnknownP      4      1       1      3       6        0

> dput(malliances)
structure(c(200L, 107L, 147L, 109L, 179L, 4L, 86L, 30L, 45L, 
48L, 74L, 1L, 164L, 51L, 107L, 90L, 119L, 1L, 124L, 46L, 79L, 
69L, 106L, 2L, 162L, 91L, 118L, 81L, 129L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = structure(list(femme = c("InghiP", 
"IngtiP", "TerangP", "TeronP", "TimungP", "UnknownP"), mari = c("InghiP", 
"IngtiP", "TerangP", "TeronP", "TimungP", "UnknownP")), .Names = c("femme", 
"mari")))

net<-graph.adjacency(malliances, mode="directed",weighted=TRUE,diag=TRUE)
```

At first glance, the results seems ok :

```
> net
IGRAPH a24d0ed DNW- 6 32 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges from a24d0ed (vertex names):
 [1] InghiP  ->InghiP   InghiP  ->IngtiP   InghiP  ->TerangP  InghiP  ->TeronP   InghiP  ->TimungP...................
```

However, str(net) or view(net) returns the following error, and I'm unable to plot anything:

```
Error in adjacent_vertices(x, i, mode = if (directed) "out" else "all") : 
  At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: The structure of `malliances` is not clear. Could you please include the output of `dput(malliances)` in your question so that we can see your exact structure.   Also,  what version of igraph are you using?  `graph.adjacency` has been replaced by the function `graph_from_adjacency_matrix`

Comment: Thanks G5W. dput added

Answer (score 1):

To me `plot(net)` does work. As for `str` and, consequently, `View`, see `?str.igraph`:

> As of igraph 1.1.1, the str.igraph function is defunct, use print_all().

```
print_all(net)
# IGRAPH 6d9db93 DNW- 6 35 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
# + edges (vertex names):
# InghiP -> InghiP, IngtiP, TerangP, TeronP, TimungP, UnknownP
# IngtiP -> InghiP, IngtiP, TerangP, TeronP, TimungP
# TerangP -> InghiP, IngtiP, TerangP, TeronP, TimungP, UnknownP
# TeronP -> InghiP, IngtiP, TerangP, TeronP, TimungP, UnknownP
# TimungP -> InghiP, IngtiP, TerangP, TeronP, TimungP, UnknownP
# UnknownP -> InghiP, IngtiP, TerangP, TeronP, TimungP, UnknownP
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. For me, plot(net) displays only five loops, no vertices and other edges.

Comment: @PhilippeRamirez, what's your version of `igraph`?

Comment: my igraph  version is 1.2.1

Comment: Sounds good enough, but you could try to update to 1.2.2. Also, make sure to run your exact reproducible example on a clean R session with `igraph:::plot.igraph(net)`. Still only loops?

Comment: There seems to be a bug when trying to update igraph within Rstudio. But finally, I don't know why but it works. Thanks Julius.

Comment: After an update, by calling `igraph:::plot.igraph(net)`, or without any extra changes? If it's one of the latter two, it sounds like before you may have had a `plot.igraph` function defined in some nonstandard way.

Comment: It worked with no changes.Thanks for your help Julius